# Why sqlalchemy with_lockmode will lock whole table for no record found condition?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, innodb

I'm using sqlalchemy to access MySQL (through Innodb). The query I use for lock is:

```
create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://root:root@localhost/tmp_db')
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
db_session.query(Transaction).filter_by(key='abc').with_lockmode('update').first()
```

There is no key = 'abc' found in table. However, the whole transaction table is locked by this query. I checked from show engine innodb status, all rows in this table is locked. Other db session can't access any row in the table, and get timeout error.

Why the whole table is locked for no record found when using with_lockmode in sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I figure out, add an index on key column to the table will solve the problem.

Comment: This had me puzzled for a second, but in order to help the next reader: key means a field but not the primary key ;)